# Instagram Messaging

Tags: android, react-native

After successful implementation of instagram login I want to send message to all the followers and following of the logged in user in a single click.

Is there any API provided by Instagram so that after successful login integration to my application I can send message to all the followers and following on a single click?

Hoping for the answer soon.Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

See [Using the Instagram Realtime API](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram/wiki/Instagram-Realtime-API) and 
[instagram-private-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api)

Comment: Thank Your for ur valuable time but still I need to send message to followers and following use after login integration. 
Can I send messeges?
Sorry because I didnt get any info about how to send messege from above link you gave